# Make use of footer_before

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, magento-1

The default RWD theme has a file named 1column.phtml in template > page. This file contains this line:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_before') ?>
```

I could make perfect use of this footer_before block, so I tried this in my local.xml:

```
<reference name="footer_before">
    <block type="core/template" name="team" as="team" template="custom/home/team.phtml" before="-">
         <block type="cms/block" name="home-team">
              <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>home-team</block_id></action>
         </block>
    </block>
</reference>
```

But it doesn't work. If I use the reference 'footer', and place `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('team') ?>` in `footer.phtml`, it does work. But I want to use this footer_before section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Default in `RWD` theme's  `page.xml` files contain below code

```
<block type="page/html_wrapper" name="footer.before" as="footer_before" translate="label">
   <label>Page Footer</label>
   <action method="setElementClass"><value>footer-before-container</value></action>
</block>
```

please check if you have this code and also check If some layout has this code . if below `remove` code exists then also it removes `footer_before` section

`<remove name="footer.before"/>`

you cannot see this section only in above two scenario

Comment: Okay, the block is there, and there is no remove, but I think I can do it on my own with this information. I had no idea where this block was defined. So I think you answered my question as good as possible haha

Comment: good answer @Murtuza Zabuawala... i  have learn one thing from you>thank u so much

Comment: you are always welcome @AmitBera , I am also learn many things from your old posts  :) .

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I just stumbled across was that this "footer before" block does not follow Magento's naming conventions. I tried referencing it by "*footer_before*" which did not work, I had to use "*footer.before*" according to RWD's *page.xml*:

```
<reference name="footer.before">
    <block type="page/html" name="foo" after="-" template="template.phtml" />
</reference>
```